# Cannot invalidate in loops?

Tags: c#, winforms, drawing

I have following code:

```
for(int I=0;I<10;I++) 
{  
 graphics.DrawImage(image, i*20,50);  
 invalidate(); 
}
```

But it redrawns just after the loop. Why?

EDIT: I am making simple movement and wants to update after each step.

Comment: Why do you care? Is it taking long time to draw each image?

Comment: You are asking the wrong question. I would not do updates in a loop like that. Tell us what you are really trying to achieve and we'll give you an alternative solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `Invalidate` does not repaint immediately, it just tells that a repaint is needed. When the method is completed, and the program is idle again, the repaint will be performed.

The quick and dirty solution is to add `Application.DoEvents()` after the `Invalidate` call, but I would suggest rewriting the logic to use a timer or something similar instead of using the loop to animate.

Comment: Acutally its just processing of the movement. the for cycle moves the enemies.

Comment: Anyway, by adding a timer that represent the frames, you will be able to avoid the hacky Application.DoEvents, and have a more consistent framerate. As written, your program will just draw those 10 frames as fast as it can, and will then depend on the speed of the CPU you are running it on.

Answer (score 3):

Because it's in a tight loop it won't actually process the redrawing until after the loop has finished. You can force it to process the redrawing message though by adding [Application.DoEvents()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.doevents.aspx) just after the invalidate like so:

```
for(int I=0;I<10;I++)
{
    graphics.DrawImage(image, i*20,50);
    invalidate(); 
    Application.DoEvents();
}
```